# For separation of variables, when $x' = g(t)h(x)$, if $h(x_0) = 0$, then why is $u(t) = x_0$ a solution?

Tags: calculus, ordinary-differential-equations, derivatives

First day of differential equations and I have a few questions:

(1) For separation of variables, when $x' = g(t)h(x)$, if $h(x_0) = 0$, then why is $u(t) = x_0$ a solution?

(2) In the picture, at the third equality, are we allowed to drop that absolute value sign because $e^a$ can never be negative? Moreover, can someone please explain the last line? The $x = u(t) \cdots$ I don't get how an indefinite integral all of a sudden transformed to a definite integral.

[image]

Comment: It is clear why $x(t)=x_{0}$ is a solution. Because $x'(t)=0$ for all $t$ and $h(x_{0})=0$ so the ODE is satisfied!

Comment: @GeorgeTsoutsinos Wow, that makes so much sense

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If $u(t)$ is a solution, than $u'(t)=0$. This can happen when $g(t)=0$ or $h(x)=0$ Since we are looking at continuous solutions, then $h(x)=0$ (otherwise $u(t)=0$ always). So if you start with $x_0$, the derivative is zero, therefore it is a constant in time.

For the second question, note that the solution cannot change sign. If it would, then you have $x=0$ at some point (assuming continuity), and then $x(t)=0$ is the solution. The correct way to integrate your solution is to put the correct limits. At $t=t_0$ you have $x=x_0$. At $t$ you have $x(t)$. So your first equation becomes
$$\int_{x_0}^{x(t)}\frac1x dx=\int_{t_0}^tg(\tau)d\tau$$